# jQuery AJAX SOAP based web services and CORS (cross origin resource sharing)

Tags: jquery, web-services, soap, cors

I have for a few weeks now been trying to get one of my jQuery AJAX SOAP based cross domain web service to work from a jQuery plugin I have written for one of my customers.
Most of the research I did seemed to indicate that it was not possible because CORS or Cross Origin Resource Sharing would only allow jasonP (GET) type calls.

**I have finally figured how to make it work and thought I would share what I had to do.**

The first thing to understand is that in a CORS aware browser, where the server is in another domain, anything other that a GET (amongst other parameters) will result in what is called a preflight check.  What this means is that the browser will ask the server for a list of options that it is allowed to perform.
Unless the server returns the exact list of options to allow a SOAP based web service the call will fail even before the actual request is made.

What you need to do is to make the web server (in my example it's IIS7.5) return the correct list of options.
You do this by configuring the web.config file in the inetpub\wwwroot folder (if you don't have one just create it and copy the following into it).

My web.config file looks like this.

***Important everything is case sensitive*** once I realized this everything just worked as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-type,soapaction,x-requested-with" />      
    </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script" />
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My jQuery AJAX code looks like this.

```
var getNextJobId = function()
{
  var se = '';
  se = se + '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>';
  se = se + '<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">';
  se = se + '<soap-env:Body>';
  se = se + '<ebas:getNextJobIdRequest xmlns:ebas="http://www.ebasetech.com">';
  se = se + '<ebas:ORGCODE>' + plugin.settings.orgcode + '</ebas:ORGCODE>';
  se = se + '</ebas:getNextJobIdRequest>';
  se = se + '</soap-env:Body>';
  se = se + '</soap-env:Envelope>';
  $.ajax(
  {
    url: params.webserviceTargetUrl,
beforeSend: function(xhr)
{
  xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "getNextJobId");
},
type: "POST",
dataType: "xml",
data: se,
crossDomain: true,
headers: {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"},
async: false,
success: function(xml)
{
  params.jobId =   $(xml).find("ebas\:JOBID").text();
},
failure: function(xml)
{
  params.webserviceFailure = $(xml).text();
},
      contentType: "charset=UTF-8"
});
}
```

Comment: Change `failure` to `error`.

Comment: +1 for SOAP in jQuery

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not meet our [Q&A format for this self-answered questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Consider separating the answer from the question.

Answer (score 5):

*"it was not possible because CORS or Cross Origin Resource Sharing would only allow jasonP (GET) type calls."*

CORS is not limited to GET methods, nor is it it limited to JSONP-style calls.

JSONP is a technique that web developers used before CORS was standardized, to perform AJAX request to hosts other than the one that served the page.  JSONP works by inserting a `<script>` tag into the page.  It requires server participation, usually by wrapping the JSON results in a call to a function, named in the AJAX call via a `callback` parameter.  See this answer:  [what-is-jsonp-all-about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about).

As you pointed out, JSONP is limited to performing a GET method, because `<script>` only performs a GET.  It has other problems, too, such as not being able to handle errors.  For example, if a 400 response is returned, the script is simply not executed by the browser, rather than executing a JS error handler for the AJAX call.

CORS is a newer standard.  It also requires server participation, in that it must handle the preflight check, and uses extra HTTP headers such as: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, which you described well in the edit to your question.  It is not limited to GET methods.  Rather, it is limited to those methods specified by the results of the preflight check in the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header.  CORS does not require the wrapping of results in a callback function or any other adjustment to the results, and it handles errors and other status codes.  See this excellent [overview of CORS](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/) for more information.

Comment: Some good additional information here and in the link you included.  Thanks to you both.