# WSDL SOAP request through Javascript

Tags: javascript, post, soap, service, wsdl

I am trying to make a request to the following wsdl web service through javascript (using a POST request):

http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?

I have tried many different things and I cannot get the answer. On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript) stackoverflow question, the most voted answer (eventhough is not the selected one) gives a code that I combined with the most voted one (to execute the code once a button is pressed) but xmlhttp.status is always 0 and the xmlhttp.responseText is empty.

All I did was copy the code, add the button to be clicked, and upload it to a server. Is there some step that I am missing? How could I get the web service request working?

Comment: [Same origin policy](https://www.google.com/search?q=Same+origin+policy&oq=Same+origin+policy)

Comment: @Musa. Does SOP mean that there is no way of doing what I want?

Comment: Not on the client, need serverside help.

Comment: @Musa So the answers to the StackOverflow question I mentioned in my question are all wrong?

Comment: In that question the op was sending the request to the same domain so SOP wont come into play.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX SOAP based web services and CORS (cross origin resource sharing)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767349/jquery-ajax-soap-based-web-services-and-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing)